# Выборка по времени в MySQL

Tags: timestamp, выборка, mysql

В таблице **tasks** есть поле **timestamp** `int(10)`, в которое записывается timestamp.

Как например MySQL запросом получить записи за 1 день?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

воспользуйтесь INTERVAL

примерно так (начиная со "вчера 00:00"):

```
SELECT * FROM TASKS WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(INTERVAL -1 day + CURRENT_DATE()) < timestamp;
```

или так начиная с сегодня 00:00

```
SELECT * FROM TASKS WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()) < timestamp;
```